# A graph with Euler circuit - is it possible to get the circuit from every vertex in the graph?

Tags: graph-theory

As mentioned in the topic,
given a graph G, that contain Euler circuit.
Does it mean that each vertex V in G can be the starting point of the Euler circuit? if so what is the proof?
else is there any way to know from which vertex it starts?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let $v_1v_2\cdots v_nv_1$ be one circuit (where some $v_i$ may be equal as the circuit goes through the same vertex multiple times). Then pick any $v_i$. Note note that
$$
v_iv_{i+1}\cdots v_nv_1v_2\cdots v_{i-1}v_i
$$
is also a circuit. So we can start the circuit wherever we like (in fact, not only any vertex, but any edge we want).

Comment: Very simple! thank you.